# How to get the time interval a ping request is sent and received

Tags: java, ping

I need to run some tests for an emulator we are using, and for that I need to test the specified RTT delay. Sometimes RTT delay will get 10x more, and at those times, I need to test if in reality that is correct. For instance if the emulator's log says at time X the RTT is set to 400ms, then I can see verify that using real application which is connected to the emulator's network. The best way to do that is using ping with timestamps. Is there any ways to specify when a ping request has been sent, and what the delay is? Or feel free to suggest any other methods my test case.

I have a Java implementation just to send ping requests!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);

    System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + ipAddress);
    System.out.println(inet.isReachable(5000));
}
```

Comment: Consider calling isReachable with ever increasing timeout values until success has achieved.

Answer (score 1):

```
String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);   
System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + ipAddress);
int uptime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println((inet.isReachable(5000) ? ((int) System.currentTimeMillis() -    uptime)+"ms" : "Request timed out"));
```